# How to properly update row with Fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a second mapping:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<tOrder>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Table("tOrder");

        Id(m => m.Id, "Ref").GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(m => m.OrderNo);
        Map(m => m.Taken);
        Map(m => m.DateRequired);

        Component(x => x.Process, m =>
        {
            m.Map(x => x.ProcessId);
        });

        References(x => x.Customer, "CustomerId").ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Works fine when I'm taking data from database, **but**, when I'm changing some fields and trying to update data in database, I am getting error: **Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 2; expected: 1** (on transaction commit).

I tried to find an answer and, one of the solutions I found was:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

in trigger.
Trigger are not mine, so I can't change it, and actually I think that I am missing something in my mapping.

How this kind of error can be solved and what am I doing wrong?

P.S Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Are you persisting your "ISession"... or are you recreating it.....as you need it?  This is a big distinction..and the difference between "connected" and "disconnected" ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update your entity........but are doing it in a "disconnected mode" (where the ISession is created as needed .. ( as opposed to having an ISession that persists ).......then you may want to use the .Merge() method.

But you need to figure out if you are doing connected or disconnected.......it changes the "strategy" and code that you will use.

```
public void UpdateMyNHiberateEntity(MyNHiberateEntity item)
{
    using (ISession session = ISessionCreator.OpenSession()) /* You won't have this method probably, but your code will create a new ISession here */
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.BeginTransaction();
            MyNHiberateEntity mergedItem = session.Merge(item);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```